# How to set the attribute Win64 to yes or no according to the bit of Windows Operating System?

Tags: wix

I use burn to install prerequisites, including the .net framework and vsto runtime. I have to know if I can install these package, so I do some registry search, for example, on 32 bit Windows, the registry of VSTO Runtime is located at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup`, but on 64 bit Windows, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup` instead.

In this case, the attribute `Win64` of the element `RegistrySearch` should be set to `no` on 32-bit Windows, `yes` for 64-bit Windows.

```
<util:RegistrySearch 
      Id="VSTORuntime" 
      Root="HKLM" 
      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" 
      Value="VSTORFeature_CLR40" 
      Variable="VSTORFeature" 
      Win64="xxxxx" />
```

Is there a way to set the attribute `Win64` of `RegistrySearch` according to the bit of OS? btw, I know the build-in `VersionNT64`, but idk how to convert that to `yes` or `no`.